# Is the empty Flutter iOS app size really > 10MB?

Tags: ios, flutter, apple-appclips

I created an empty Flutter project, removed `uses-material-design: true` and then tested the app size. To test the app size, I archived it in Xcode, and used ad hoc distribution with app thinning to get an "App Thinning Size Report.txt" The resulting app size is between 13.5MB and 21MB depending on the device.

(I was hoping to use Flutter but also wanted to be able to make an iOS App Clip and Android Instant App, but it seems infeasible given that an empty app already goes over the size restriction.)

Comment: Yes this has been a known issue for quite some time with no ETA in sight: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/ios-app-clip